# Matlab - Euclidian distance between two matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, euclidean-distance

I have declared 2 matrixes like this:

```
a = [ 1 2;
      11 12];


[m, n] = size(a);

b = a(2,:); 

dist( b , a ); % the first column is not interesting
```

This works, I get a vector

```
[ 10.0499 9.0000 ]
```

However if I want to add a column or a line to my matrix a:

```
 a = [ 1  2  3 ;
       11 12 13];
```

then apply the same algorithm, than above, ignoring or not the first column, I get this error:

```
Error using -
Matrix dimensions must agree
```

I have no idea why it does not work, can someone explain to me please?

Actually I don't even know how to retrieve the way this euclidian distance is computed, I failed at trying to retrieve those values [ 10.0499 9.0000 ] by hand. 
The Matlab mathworks manual says he algorithm used is the following:

```
d = sum((x-y).^2).^0.5
```

Any help

Comment: I'd turn the question the other way around. What kind on distance you need to use?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/dist.html note the dimensions

Comment: I am supposed to adapt one imaging algorithm from matlab to java. For that I need to understand how things work. 
The fact is in the WORKING algorithm, they use the function D=dist(B, A), A being a 6188x6 matrix and B being a 1x6 vector (corresponding to one line of A).
The output D is a 6188x6 matrix.
What troubles me is that on the matlab documentation (see vish's link) it is said that B should be of dimension SxR, and A of dimension RxQ, the output would be of dimension SxQ. Which is absolutely not the case here, A is not inverted at all. And still it works. I am really, really puzzled

Comment: D is SxQ = 1x6188. So the question is: did the dist function automatically invert my A matrix?
Ultimately, how is the dist function supposed to work, if I want to check simple results by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the [dist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/dist.html) function when called with two arguments works like this:

> Z = dist(W,P) takes an SxR weight matrix and RxQ input matrix and
>   returns the SxQ matrix of **distances between W's rows and P's columns**. 
>   dist(P',P) returns the same result as dist(P).

That is, if you do this:

```
a = [ 1  2  3 ;
      11 12 13]
b = a(2,:) % Then b = [11 12 13]
```

...and call:

```
dist(b, a)
```

It will try to compute the distance between **b's rows** (in this case, only a row with three numbers, that is, a 3D point) and **a's columns** (each column has two numbers, that is, a 2D point). Measuring a distance between them makes no sense.

The reason it worked on your first example was because the matrix was square (2x2). Therefore, you're computing distances between a row (2D) to the other columns (also 2D).

Comment: Thank you for you reply Rafael! I explained in the above comment that the funny part is: in the original code, I have B as a 1x6 vector, and A as a 1688x6 matrix (which is not squared right). And dist(B, A) WILL output a 1x6188 matrix! A was not even inverted before! Do you have an explanation to this? It can't be that the dist() function sometimes invert one input matrix for you..

Comment: Well, if B is a 1x6 vector, we could interpret it like a 6D point, and matrix A has 1688 points in 6D. It returns a 1x1688 vector where each vector represents the distance of "point B" to each "point in A", that is, 1688 distances. It seems ok. :)

Comment: That is correct. My point is the documentation says it expects a SxR as first matrix, then a RxQ as second one. Here in my case, that is a B has SxR dimensions, and A has QxR. So I understand that dist(B, A) should not work. Moreover they wrote in an exemple: W = rand(4,3); P = rand(3,1); Z = dist(W, P) In my case it's as if P = rand(1, 3) ! And I can't explain why it works.. That's inconsistent!

Comment: Forget about it. The guy who coded in Matlab defined his OWN dist function, overriding the Matlab dist function. His funciton does the SAME computation than Matlab except that, you can guees now, it inverts your second matrix inside the function. Damn. Jerks. 
Thank for all your help! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

A distance by definition is a single number, not a vector. The fact that you've getting a vector for matrices of the same size already indicates that something is wrong. In particular, it gives you distance between each of the corresponding column vectors to each other. So it doesn't work when your matrices are of different sizes. A distance between matrices is not defined in any one particular way. I don't know of a notion of Euclidean distance between two matrices.